# regular expression:match a word and a length

Tags: regex

I need help to do this regex. The sentence can't be less than 4 letters, and it can't match any of these word `(test1,test2 and test3)`

I know how to do each one separately but not together.

First condition `^.{4,}$`

Second condition `^((?!test1|test2|test3).)*$`

How to do both so that:-

1. "hello" will pass
2. "hel" will fail
3. "test1" will fail although it is more than 4 letters long
4. "test2" will fail although it is more than 4 letters long
5. "test3" will fail although it is more than 4 letters long

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this one:

```
(?=^.{4,}$)(^((?!test1|test2|test3).)*$)
```

Or:

```
(?=^.{4,}$)(^((?!test(1|2|3)).)*$)
```

Or:

```
(?=^.{4,}$)(^((?!test[1-3]).)*$)
```

Comment: I used lookahead technique, 1st lookahead seek 4th size string, after I reset it by using `?=` and move to other lookahead

Answer (score 1):

Use the below:

```
/^(?!.*test[1-3]).{4,}$/
```