# positive look behind doesn't work but look ahead works

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I have string which contains **all digits**.

I want to check whether:

1. all the digits are in the range of `0-4`, and
2. the minimum length of the string should be `5`

So, I used this regex:

```
(?=^\d{5,}$)(^[0-4]*$) //works
```

As expected this does the job

But the above regex when used with positive look behind doesn't work

```
(?<=^\d{5,}$)(^[0-4]*$) //doesn't work
```

Why does `positive look behind` doesn't work but `look ahead` work's in this case

**EDIT**

Yes,I can use

`^[0-4]{5,}$`

But the question is why `look-behind` didnt work in the above case

This was in reference to [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975750/regular-expressionmatch-a-word-and-a-length) question where `lookahead` worked but not `lookbehind`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Shouldn't you look from behind, to match a "look **behind** assertion" ?

i.e.

```
(^[0-4]*$)(?<=^\d{5,}$)
```

As it stands now, you want this:

- *following* 5 or more characters (that comprise the entire string)
- the beginning of a string
- containing `[0-4]`

Which basically reduces to

- `false`

Comment: ohh..nice..this may be irritating but why cant it be `(?<=^\d{5,}$)(^[0-4]*$)` this could mean look behind for 5 or more digits before matching `[0-4]*`

Comment: That is what it means. But if you look behind, at the beginning of the string, you will find nothing. If you look behind, from the end of the string, you will find something, but then you are at the end of the string and cannot find `[0-4]` in front of you. A regex is really a pattern that needs to fit on the string, it's not just a bunch of magic spells.

Comment: If you would remove the `^` and `$` anchors, your regex might match `99999222`, because it can find `[0-4]* == 222` while seeing `\d{5,} == 99999` behind the point where the `[0-4]*` started to match.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you haven't anchored the look behind to the end of input.
Try this:

```
(?<=^\d{5,})(^[^5-9]*)$ // $ at end (and removed now-redundant $ from each look behind)
```

Also, negative negatives are harder to read. Just use `[0-4]` instead of `[^5-9]`.

Finally, why not use this:

```
^[0-4]{5,}$
```

Comment: nice..I actually wanted to know why look behind doesnt work..This was in reference to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12975750/regular-expressionmatch-a-word-and-a-length) question where look ahead worked but not lookbehind

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. A look-behind *before* an `^` anchor basically defaults to `false`, that's the problem.